# Crontab Magento or Crontab System?

Tags: magento2, module, cron

I have a question, magento uses a cron own or uses the cron of the same operating system?

And how could I configure it to make a cron of a specific module? In my case I want to export every "x" time the products of my store to make feeds with the module "Product Feed Export Module"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Operating system's crontab executes magento system cron and then magento system cron executes all the crons exist in magento modules which includes custom modules too.

It works like this:

1.) In operating system crontab you need to setup magento crons like this:

```
#~ MAGENTO START
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v Ran jobs by schedule >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/update/cron.php >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/setup.cron.log
#~ MAGENTO END
```

2.) First cron command cron:run, it collects the crons from crontab.xml file of all modules and creates the entries into the database table `'cron_schedule'` with the time when each cron needs to be executed.

3.) Now as the `cron:run` is executing repeatedly next time when it will run it will check the `cron_schedule` table and execute the crons which have same scheduled_time as the current time. Also this cron will schedule the crons to be executed into the `cron_schedule` table.

To setup/create cron for custom module.

1.) Create crontab.xml inside module's etc folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job instance="Namespace\Modulename\Cron\Export" method="execute" name="namespace_modulename_export">
            <schedule>*/5 * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

2.) Create your cron file inside module's Cron folder

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Modulename\Cron;

class Export
{
    /**
     * Execute the cron
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function execute()
    {
        // write your cron code        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Magento2 is using the cron of the same operating system that mean you have to configure it. 
Magento2 support a command that auto create system crontab:

```
php bin/Magento cron:install [--force]
```

After run above command, you can see system cron by this command:

```
crontab -l
```

A sample follows:

```
#~ MAGENTO START
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v Ran jobs by schedule >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/update/cron.php >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/setup.cron.log
#~ MAGENTO END
```

Check more detail [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html)

Answer (score 1):

Create **crontab.xml** under:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/crontab.xml

with below contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="export_products" instance="Vendor\Module\Cron\Run" method="execute">
            <schedule>*/5 * * * *</schedule>-->
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

Create **Run.php** under:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Cron/Run.php

with below contents:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Cron;

class Run 
{
   protected $_logger;
   public function __construct(
       \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
   ) 
    {
     $this->_logger = $logger;
    }

   public function execute()
   {
        // Write your export logic here
        $this->_logger->debug('Cron run successfully');
        return $this;
   }
}
```

Above method only add this to magento 2 cron schedule. Above configuration show that the cron will execute at every 5 mins. You can change the time according to your requirement.

**@Lee** already mentioned how you need to set cron for magento 2.

***Note: Above cron will run only when your magento 2 cron is enabled and running correctly.***